# How can I correctly assign the value of a key from another key inside a Javascritp object?

Tags: javascript, object, reference

Assuming that I have the following `config.js` file containing an object

```js
module.exports = {
    css: {
        src: './src/sass/**/*.scss',
        dist: './dist/css/',
        watch: './src/sass/**/*.scss',
    }
}
```

I have two identical values for `css.src` and `css.watch`; how can I modify this to correctly set the value of  `watch` to be equal to `src` without having to write that value again?

Comment: Put it in a variable? `const path = './src/sass/**/*.scss';`?

Answer (score -2):

Use variables to refer same value or below

```
module.exports = {
        css: {
            src: './src/sass/**/*.scss',
            dist: './dist/css/',
            watch: module.exports.css.src
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you even tried this code? It does not work.